# how do I select distinct data?

Tags: sql

I'm new in SQL and I this for my uni project. I have a table with columns  `Rego, FirstRego, LastRego, RegoDue`.

Suppose I have the following data:

```
  Rego      FirstRego                      LastRego                      RegoDue
YGF 615 2011-04-07 00:00:00.000 2011-04-07 00:00:00.000 2012-04-07 00:00:00.000
YGF 615 2011-04-07 00:00:00.000 2012-04-07 00:00:00.000 2013-04-07 00:00:00.000
ZIR 377 2012-10-05 00:00:00.000 2012-10-05 00:00:00.000 2013-10-05 00:00:00.000
ZIR 377 2012-10-05 00:00:00.000 2013-10-05 00:00:00.000 2014-10-05 00:00:00.000
ZJT 795 2012-10-31 00:00:00.000 2012-10-31 00:00:00.000 2013-10-31 00:00:00.000
ZSU 823 2012-04-30 00:00:00.000 2012-04-30 00:00:00.000 2013-04-30 00:00:00.000
```

In the query output I want the `Rego` to be once with the highest `RegoDue` i.e the output should look like:

```
Rego      FirstRego                      LastRego                      RegoDue
YGF 615 2011-04-07 00:00:00.000 2012-04-07 00:00:00.000 2013-04-07 00:00:00.000
ZIR 377 2012-10-05 00:00:00.000 2013-10-05 00:00:00.000 2014-10-05 00:00:00.000
ZJT 795 2012-10-31 00:00:00.000 2012-10-31 00:00:00.000 2013-10-31 00:00:00.000
ZSU 823 2012-04-30 00:00:00.000 2012-04-30 00:00:00.000 2013-04-30 00:00:00.000
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What about GROUP BY Rego + MAX() ?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select * 
From Tbl T1
Where RegoDue =
(
    Select Max(RegoDue)
    From Tbl T2
    Where T2.Rego = T1.Rego
)
```

Comment: Please before post anything read [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Provide a full answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you want to find the latest rego due date. Once you have this you can join on it to filter out the undesired results.

```
select
    t.Rego, t.FirstRego, t.LastRego, lr.LatestRegoDue as RegoDue
from Table1 t
    join
    (
        select
           Rego, max(RegoDue) as LatestRegoDue
        from Table1
        group by Rego
    ) lr on t.Rego = lr.Rego and t.RegoDue = lr.LatestRegoDue
```